# Is Memcached get and put methods are thread safe

Tags: multithreading, get, memcached, put

Is there any chance of getting a garbled value for a key in memcached in multi thread environment?. If so how to avoid it with minimal time of synchronization?.

Using Java client to access memcached server

Comment: Your question title is written differently from the question text. The accepted answer seems to imply that the method are not thread safe because of the title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Memcache will return a value that somebody wrote previously, and not a garbled value. If you get/modify/put you have no guarantee that the put applies to the same value as the get. Use the cas (compare and set) operation if you need to synchronize.

Comment: is this behaviour documented?  I would like to read if you can link to docs.

Comment: This documents the behavior: http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#What_are_memcached_threads? "Operating on the cache internals are under global locks" so you can't have two requests modifying one key and garbling it.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#Is_memcached_atomic?, is what i am searching for, thanks