# Concurrent operation in a synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

There is a scenario in my Application where a Thread under its run method while(true) condition does this OPeration .

Under its while true condition , it continuasally fetches information from a  External Data Source(Memcache)  , adds / removes content from it,  depending on newly  logged in or logged out users , and finally  updates  it back to Memcache .

Some Snipet of code

```
public class MonitoringThread extends Thread 
{
public void run() {
while(true)
String  response = Memcache.get("USERINFO");
// Some checks will be made on response and builds a new response and updates back to Memcache .
synchronized (response)
{
Memcache.set("USERINFO" , response) ;
}
}
}
```

My question is

1. **I have kept a Synchronized block on  a set operation (Is this correct ) or it should be done while doing a get Operation ??**
2. **And the parameter that is passed to the Synchronied block , whether this should be this (the class itself) or the String  response**

Some more information .

Our Application runs on 5 Web Server instances controlled by  a Load Balancer . ( All these 5 Instances will do that get Operation and Updates Data back )

Please share your ideas .

Thanks for reading , have a great day .

**Edited Part**

Thanks for the response ,

I have changed the synchronized block parameter , please let me know what is fesable appproach below

**Option 1**

Using synchronied block in the Thread

```
synchronized (Memcache.class)
{
Memcache.set("USERINFO" , response) ;
}


class Memcache
{
public static boolean set(String key, Object value) {
MemcacheClient.set(key, 0, value);
}
```

Or

Using Synchronied block in the Memcache class itself

```
class Memcache
{
synchronized (Memcache.class)
{
public static boolean set(String key, Object value) {
MemcacheClient.set(key, 0, value);
}
```

// other methods
    }

Comment: You still don't explain why you want a synchronized block in the first place.

Comment: As i said there are 5 instances of Web servers , user might be logged in from web 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , or 5 and same thing during logged out also .

SO i was maintining the User Logged in Information in the memcache

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need a synchronized block. Do you actually understand what synchronized does? It doesn't have anything to do with multiple Java processes. The fact that you have 5 web servers is irrelevant to thread synchronization.

Comment: Ya agreed what i was trying to explain is that , Users might be logged in or Logged out , i am trying to maintain all the Logged in User Information in the Memcache . and in case if logout happens , updating the data in Mmecache

Comment: And that still doesn't explain why you would need a synchronized block. Have you read somewhere that your memcache client wasn't thread-safe and needed external synchronization?

Comment: I was using Synhronized as this is a COncurrent Operation happening under a while true condition , So you mean to say that i dont need synchronied here ?? I see that for any concurrent operation , Memcache uses cas . and i cant use that for some reasons

Comment: I don't know about your memcache client, but I would guess that it's thread-safe: a cache is generally intended to be used by multiple threads. So no, you probably don't need any synchronized block.

Comment: could you please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611799/is-memcached-get-and-put-methods-are-thread-safe

Comment: Have you read the accepted answer? It explicitely says that memcache is thread-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do with this synchronized block, and why you need synchronization in the first place. What is the shared state that you want to protect with a synchronized block?

Anyway, what's sure is that this snippet doesn't make much sense. `synchronized(response)` means that two threads won't be able to execute the synchronized block if they both received the same String instance (the same object, not just the same characters) from the cache. This is very unlikely, and is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Locking on a String is unlikely to be useful as you are locking on a different object each time.  `Memcache` should perform any locking it needs and if it doesn't you need to lock on the same object e.g. `Memcache.class`